# iReport - Lines of the first page ending on the second page

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm doing a report to Excel in iReport 3.7.2. In preview of iReport, it appears normal. When I print my report from Excel, the lines of the first page are ending at the beginning of the second page before the page header band.

These lines comes from the database.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem.

When I used the JExcelAPIExporter class instead of JRXlsExporter, the form was generated correctly.